# Module Unavailable (Not Misspelled / Properly Declared)

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, module

I have an issue loading my module. I am getting an error of:

> `Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'cashierWcnp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

My module declaration is something like this:

`'use strict';
angular.module('cashierWcnp', ['ui.router','cashierCore','ngMessages']);`

This is a duplicate of a fully functioning module of:

`'use strict';
angular.module('cashierAlipayWap', ['ui.router','cashierCore','ngMessages']);`

For some reason, the last one works just fine when it starts recognizing it here:

`'use strict';
angular.module('cashierDepositPage', ['ui.router','cashierCore', 'cashierDebitCard', 'cashierAlipayWap', 'cashierWcnp', 'cashierAtmOtc', 'cashierAtmOtcConfirm', 'cashierBankTransfer', 'cashierBankTransferConfirm']);`

except when `cashierWcnp` is included, which then throws an error `Error: $injector:nomod Module Unavailable`

What am I missing here?

[EDIT]: FYI, the structure of `cashierWcnp` is exactly the same with the fully functioning `cashierAlipayWap` (only in different module names).

Comment: First thing to check. Is the JS file that contains cashierWcnp definitely loaded? I.e. Can you see it's source in devtools?

Comment: @Kildareflare seems like it is not being loaded. What reason could it not be included in the source when it is right there on my app folder structure, along with the existing ones?

Comment: Got it. It seems like I have to rebuild my entire app with Gulp. This is something I easily overlooked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the JS file that contains cashierWcnp is definitely loaded.

Check the index.html file to ensure that **cashierWcnp.js** is included by a script tag like so

```
<script src="path-to-your-file/cashierWcnp.js"></script>
```

If your project was set up such that a grunt or gulp task compiles all javascript files into one file (e.g., my-app.js). Then you need to make sure that the **cashierWcnp.js** file is on the path to be processed by the grunt or gulp task.

Also, make sure you have actually run the gulp / grunt task after adding the **cashierWcnp.js** file to your project.